# typescript generic function to convert any to array of any

Tags: typescript

I want a write a simple utility function that takes any argument and if the arg is not already array return array with a single element, that arg.

examples:

```js
toArray('hey') => ['hey']
toArray(['hey']) => ['hey']
```

implementation:

```js
export type ToArr<T> = T extends any[] ? T : T[];
export const toArray = <T>(arg: T): ToArr<T> => {
  return (Array.isArray(arg) ? arg : [arg]) as ToArr<T>;
};
```

that's works fine, as long as the arg passed to `toArray` is not of type 'any':

```js
type testType1 = ToArr<string>; // string[]    - ok
type testType2 = ToArr<string[]>; // string[]  - ok
type testType3 = ToArr<any[]>; // any[]        - ok
type testType4 = ToArr<any>; // any            - not ok! should be any[]

let myVar:any = 'test'
let myVarArr = toArray(myVar) //               - type of myVarArr is any instead of any[]
```

what's wrong with my implementation of `toArr` generic? why does any extends any[] (the condition in the generic function)? how can I modify this function to handle cases where arg is of type any?

for clarification: I want `toArray` will always return a value with type of array.

```js
export type ToArr<T> = T extends any[] ? T : T[];
```

Comment: In `ToArr<any>` how would you know that `any` is not an array?

Comment: I don't know that. but i want to make sure the toArray will always return an array

Comment: What you're trying to do is neither possible nor really needed, as you can index `myVarArr` and pass it into functions that require arrays. Have you encountered any actual problem with your code?

Comment: well yes. `(userProp) => toArray(userProp).map(...)`, i dont get suggestions on the IDE on what returns from toArray (like map) because the IDE can't say for sure that is an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be overcomplicating things. A simple union type should work.

```
const toArray = <T>(arg: T | T[]): T[] => {
  return Array.isArray(arg) ? arg : [arg];
};

let myVar: any = 'test'
let myVarArr = toArray(myVar) // type is any[]
```

Comment: yup... guess I overcomplicated it

Comment: actually, i don't understand what it means `<T>(arg: T | T[])`, what does `arg: T | T[]` means? what if arg is of type literal? what does a union between a literal and array of literals means? what if arg is an array? how does an array of arrays resolve to a simple array?

a further explanation on this would be appreciated.